# Why client socket connection is not closed after all data received from server?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm learning socket programming in python,

**Server Code:**

```
import socket

srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
srvsock.bind(('', 23000))
srvsock.listen(5)

while True:
    clisock, (rem_host, rem_port) = srvsock.accept()
    print "conection established with host %s and port %s" % (rem_host, rem_port)
    while True:
        strg = clisock.recv(20)
        if not strg:
            print 'conection closed'
            clisock.close()
            break
        clisock.send(strg)
```

**Client Code:**

```
import socket

clisock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clisock.connect(('', 23000))
clisock.send("Hello World rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr dsadsadsa tttttt\n")
while True:
    data = clisock.recv(20)
    print type(data)
    if not data:
        clisock.close()
        break
    print data
```

I'm sending data stream from client to server and at the same time receiving data from server, after successful data transmission, the server not closing client connection. Did I miss any thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused because the server keeps reading data from the client until it reads no data. This only happens when the connected client closes its connection. Until then, the server socket will block (i.e. temporarily suspend operations) until the client sends more data.

Bottom line: either the client or the server has to indicate that it no longer intends to send data over the connection.

You can fix the client by adding the line

```
clisock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

before the `for` loop in the client. This indicates that no more data will be sent.

Comment: Just a quick note in addition: one of the most important parts of protocol design is ensuring that protocol units (packets, dataframes, whatever) can be separated from each other. You were trying to implement a protocol where no "end of message" detection was possible, and no "end of transmission" was being sent.

Answer (score 0):

server code:

```
while True:
    clisock, (rem_host, rem_port) = srvsock.accept()
    print "conection established with host %s and port %s" % (rem_host, rem_port)
    while True:
        strg = clisock.recv(20)
        print '[message from client:] %s'%strg
        clisock.send(strg)
        print 'about to close with client'
        clisock.close()
        print 'connection closed with client'
        break
```

client code :

```
clisock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clisock.connect(('', 23000))
clisock.send("Hello World rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr dsadsadsa tttttt\n")
while True:
    data = clisock.recv(20)
    print '[Message from server :]%s'%data
    print 'about to close server connection'
    clisock.close()
    print 'server connection closed'
    break
```

This will work out in your case, holdenweb has proper a proper answer why your code is not behaving as expected in above code client only sends one message and closes the connection as well as server listens only for one message per client and closes connection to that client single client -- single connection ---- single message